# Generate javascript from typescript AST?

Tags: parsing, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript1.6, typescript1.7

I'm using the built-in parser to generate the AST from source code:

```
const ts = require('typescript')
//...
const ast = ts.createSourceFile(filename, fs.readFileSync(filename).toString(), ts.ScriptTarget.ES6, true)
```

Given an arbitrary node in the tree, how do I generate the typescript from the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> an arbitrary node in the tree, how do I generate the typescript from the node

You cannot in the current version of the compiler. The only node that supports generation is `SourceFile`.

There is talk to make the emitter more split (transformer based like the Babel emitter).

Comment: So given a node, is there any way to get back the corresponding source code? I notice that there are `pos` and `end` properties.

Comment: There is a `getTextOfNode` function in the `ts` namespace

Comment: ts.getTextOfNode is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks